# Getting error: Use of unresolved identifier "LinkingObjects"

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm

I am getting the following error in my Realm Swift (1.03.1) schema after updating to Cocoapods 1.0.0.

Error:

Use of unresolved identifier "LinkingObjects"

On sample below:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Metric: Object {
    dynamic var UUID: String = ""

    let linkingDimensions = LinkingObjects(fromType: Dimension.self, property: "metric")

    dynamic var createdAt: NSDate = NSDate()
    dynamic var createdBy: Int = CreatedBy.System.rawValue

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "UUID"
    }
}
```

I've tried:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods // on all cocoapods files
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
```

I then reinstalled, to no avail. I can't seem to find reference to this issue on the Realm Github issues page.

Where should I look to see why Xcode can't find Realm. How can I check if Realm has been properly installed when Cocoapods generates the workspace files and dependencies?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by clearing Xcode's derived project data.

Selecting Window -> Projects menu and deleting the appropriate projects.

Comment: I too cleared CocoaPods cache, reinstalled pods, deleted derived data and all that several times but still having this issue.