# Error using LinkingObjects(fromType:property:) - Use of unresolved identifier 'LinkingObjects'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, realm

Following the Realm Swift documentation i declared some classes `Car` and `Tour` like this:

```
import RealmSwift


class Car: Object {
   dynamic var id = ""
   let tours = List<Tour>()
}

class Tour: Object {
   dynamic var id = "" 
   let cars = LinkingObjects(fromType: Car.self, property: "tours")
}
```

When I try to build this, i get an error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'LinkingObjects'`. I tried to clean Xcode's Derived Data like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409089/getting-error-use-of-unresolved-identifier-linkingobjects) post says, but the build still fails.

Does anyone know, how to resolve this error?

Comment: That seems to imply you're not running the latest version of Realm. You're using the CocoaPods tag there; have you run `pod update` to ensure that CocoaPods has updated Realm to the latest version?

Comment: When i run `pod update` CocoaPods still installs version 0.97.0 and not the latest one.

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem right. It should be updating to `1.0.0` at this point. Have you explicitly set 0.97.0 to be the target version in your `Podfile`?

Comment: No i wasn't specific about the version, but i updated my CocoaPods and now i've got version `1.0.0`. Everything works fine now. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I resolved the error by using

```
 var cars : Car? {
     return linkingObjects(Car.self, forProperty: "tours").first
 }
```

for a to-one-relationship. It seems that i've installed an older version of Realm (0.97.0) and checked the wrong documentation.

Comment: Haha that's good for 0.97.0, but the new `LinkingObjects` feature is a lot more streamlined than that. I'd still recommend you upgrade to 1.0.0 if you can. 0.97.0 is quite old at this point and a lot of bug fixes were added in later versions!